# Magento 2.How to get cart product collection in product view page

Tags: magento2, cart

I got cart product collections by following code

```
    $quoteId = $objectManager-> create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId();
    $cartData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository')->get($quoteId)->getAllVisibleItems();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

But once i delete product from cart it doesn't return exact value,
i can get the correct answer after i refresh the cache.

What is the issue in it and how to get the solution for this problem.?

Comment: Can you please tell me  they you need this?

Comment: How you will get quote id?

Comment: I just need to know the explanation of these lines and any other methods to get the cart product solution?